# Best practice - How to test if a string exists in Java?

Tags: java

I render some data based on a condition. The backing method performs a check if a string exists. But I don't know if I can be happy with the compare to `null`?

```
public boolean isString(MyClass var) {
   return null != var.getMyString();
}
```

Could it be done better?

Comment: What do you want to check? If string contains something? If a string is not null? If a variable is incstance of string?

Comment: It's difficult to know how to answer this question.  You want to know whether a string reference is null, so you're doing the right thing by comparing it with null!

Comment: @Morpheus, why would you convert it to an array instead of just testing `!"".equals(var.getMyString())` or `var.getMyString().length() != 0`?

Comment: @Morpheus That would throw a NullPointerException if var.getMyString() == null.

Comment: Got the requirement wrong. Dang!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like [`StringUtils.isNotBlank()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(var.getMyString())
```

It performs extra `trim()` which is desirable most of the time. If not, use [`StringUtils.isNotEmpty()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). Another advantage: it uses `CharSequence` so you can pass `String`, `StringBuilder`, etc.

Comment: Man, this is really just great.  I took a look @ some of the other methods that StringUtils offers and it's fantastic.  For just about every "positive" method there is also a "negative".  e.g. `isBlank()` vs `isNotBlank()`...

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
return var.getMyString() != null && !var.getMyString.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly common to also check for the empty string, dependending upon your actual requirements surrounding the existence of the string.